# word2vec logging missing values

Tags: python-3.x, gensim, word2vec

Im using gensim version '3.8.3'

when im running for model Word2Vec and FastText `build_vocab` and `train` 
the logs from those functions are missing the values

for example part of the logs of  `build_vocab` of FastText

```
08/09/2020 08:19:18 AM [INFO] collecting all words and their counts
08/09/2020 08:19:18 AM [INFO] PROGRESS: at sentence #%i, processed %i words, keeping %i word types
08/09/2020 08:19:18 AM [INFO] PROGRESS: at sentence #%i, processed %i words, keeping %i word types
08/09/2020 08:19:18 AM [INFO] PROGRESS: at sentence #%i, processed %i words, keeping %i word types
```

the index is missing and printed as `i`

is there a way to solve it? is it a version bug?

Comment: How did you install gensim & verify its version-number? Are you using a standard Python (aka 'CPython')? On what OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [per the discussion on the `gensim` project issue you opened for the same problem](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2914), this appears to be some problem with your Python installation's logging functionality that is unrelated to `gensim` or the word2vec algorithm. And in some respects, the problem is more foundational & concerning, as it indicates some replacement of core functionality with a sloppy alternative.

For example, if you see a similar problem with the test code...

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(message)s')

logging.info(
    "TEST A %i B %.2f C %.0f D %i F %i",
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5
)
```

...then the problem is in the core `logging` module.

I would suggest starting from a fresh development environment – at the very least, a fresh separate Python environment (using either the core `venv` functionality or an environment-manager like `conda`), and if practical even a fresh machine/OS install.

If the problem with the above simple test code goes away in a fresh environment, then you can incrementally reproduce the original environment by adding libraries/tools, checking for working logging after each major step, and if the problem recurs you'll have a better idea of which step introduced it.